# Change locale (language) but retain form data

Tags: spring, forms, internationalization, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring and Thymeleaf to present a form on a web-page. The user can change language by clicking a button on the page. This will send a `get` request for the same page again, but with the requested locale appended as a parameter, e.g. `<a href="?locale=en_GB">British English</a>`.

I have a requirement that if the user changes languages after already filling in some of the form fields, then the entered values should be maintained.

I guess I'll have to post the form up to the server, so that it can repopulate the form when it re-renders the page in the new language. Is there a standard Spring/Thymeleaf way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got this working now by using a `CookieLocaleResolver` as my `localeResolver` bean. Then, when the user clicks on the button, set the cookie and post the form.

```
<a onclick="document.cookie='myLocaleCookie=en_GB'; $('#the-form').submit();>British English</a>
```

I'd still be interested to know if there's a better or more standard way of doing this though.